# Append Criteria query to previous query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

I have a String array named `andOrButtonFilter` which stores `and` `or` filters selected by user.

Also two `ArrayList` named `column` and `value` storing column names and their values respectively.

I want the current query to append to the previous query and show the results
But my query is not being appended to the previous query, it is showing individual results.

For eg:
if `name=xyz` is first query and
`age=26` is second query
It does not results with `name=xyz` and `age=26` . It is only showing results for `age=26` when executed for the second time.

Where am I going wrong?

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
for (int i=0; i<andOrButtonFilter.length; i++)
    {

        if(andOrButtonFilter[i]=="and")
        {
            Conjunction conjunction =Restrictions.conjunction();
            if ((column.get(i) != null) && (value.get(i)!=null))
            {
                conjunction.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i))));
                criteriaQuery.add(conjunction);
            }
        }

        else if(andOrButtonFilter[i]=="or")
        {
            Disjunction disjunction =Restrictions.disjunction();
            if ((column.get(i) != null) && (value.get(i)!=null))
            {
                disjunction.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i))));
                criteriaQuery.add(disjunction);
            }
        }

        else 
        {

            criteriaQuery.add(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find a few problems with you code.

1) You compare strings with == instead of equals. So your code always goes into the last section  `criteriaQuery.add(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i)));`

2) In your conjunction/disjunction code you still use Restrictions.or which is kind of wrong. You don't even need Restrictions.or or Restrictions.and because Conjunction is adding the restrictions with AND anyway and Disjunction is adding with OR anyway.

3) On each iteration you add separate disjunction which is basically a single criterion and won't work as you expect.

I would try with something like:

```
 Disjunction disjunction =Restrictions.disjunction();
 Conjunction conjunction =Restrictions.conjunction(); 
 for (int i=0; i<andOrButtonFilter.length; i++)
    {
        if("and".equals(andOrButtonFilter[i]))
        {         
            if ((column.get(i) != null) && (value.get(i)!=null))
            {
                conjunction.add(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i)));             
            }
        }
        else if("or".equals(andOrButtonFilter[i]))
        {           
            if ((column.get(i) != null) && (value.get(i)!=null))
            {
                disjunction.add(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i)));              
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            criteriaQuery.add(Restrictions.eq(column.get(i), value.get(i)));
        }
    }
    criteriaQuery.add(conjunction);
    criteriaQuery.add(disjunction);
```

I am not saying that exact code will work because I haven't tested it ;) but you get the idea and you can debug from there.

Comment: I tried your code and now the` if`else` block is being visited as per the respective `and or` filter but still the query is not being appended to the previous query only the last value is being queried. Can you tell what could the reason be?